# Clicking URL Link on TTStyledTextLabel doesn't push a new page

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, three20

When I am clicking URL link on TTStyleTextLabel, it doesn't push a new page.
But when I looked at the TTCatalog, they don't have any method in the styledtexttestcontroller which seem to open up the webpage.
So how does TTCatalog do that?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have the TTNavigator to map from url to TTWebController. In the sample TTCatalog app you have:

```
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
```

This will let the http:// be mapped to TTWebController in case it does not have any other mapped view controller.